# Why Edits must be at least 6 characters?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I noticed a small typo: "diggest" instead of "digest" in 
[this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/13845/241):

This is exactly one character. No more changes are needed. Why is this simple fix unsupported?
Why can't we just fix one small typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stackexchange policy to disallow minor edits for low-rep users. Either game the system with faux edits that are greater than six characters, or participate in the site until your rep is sufficient to make one-character edits. For example, I just made two one-character edits in a row to your question. I don't know at what rep they allow me to do that, but I can.

Comment: The [edit privilege](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) is granted at 1000 rep.

Answer (score 3):

I'll quote [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81898/163294) from Meta Stack Overflow:

> The 6-char minimum edit restriction is in place to discourage you (the
>   editor) from doing something stupid: submitting an incomplete or
>   pointless edit. But ultimately, that's just a guideline - there's
>   certainly nothing preventing you from doing something stupid in >= 6
>   characters, and you may find on occasion that you can make a useful
>   and important edit in < 6 characters. Making the system (which cannot
>   itself judge the quality of any given edit) strictly enforce such a
>   guideline doesn't necessarily solve any real problem. Since all
>   suggested edits are reviewed, any user abusing this to post worthless
>   edits will quickly find them rejected, just like a user adding 6+
>   characters of gibberish would.

This is actually by design.

Comment: So what are we supposed to do in this case? Only one character needs deleting.

Comment: Find more ways to improve the post like so: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/posts/13845/revisions

Comment: This means gaming the system to find a way around a useless restriction. I will not do that.

Comment: That wasn't the point of my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that this kind of edit would be rejected as too minimal.

Each edit brings a question or an answer closer to being converted to a community wiki post. Enforcing the limit forces users to submit only substantial edits. As you can see in Matt's edit, there was more than one typo in the answer.
Only correcting one of them wouldn't have improved the post as it could have been by carefully proofreading it.